# Moment of Inertia: uniform rigid rod on smooth plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, rotational-dynamics, acceleration, moment-of-inertia

Consider a rod of length $b$ and mass $m$ on a smooth horizontal plane. A force is applied to one end of the rod.

What is the acceleration $a$ and angular acceleration $\alpha$ of the other end of the rod.

At what distance should the force be applied such that the one end of the rod has initial acceleration of zero.

The essence of the question is, at what point does a rod rotate about given the force is applied a distance $x$ from one end of the rod?

Comment: This looks like you're asking us to derive a solution for you. Is there a specific concept that you are asking about?

Comment: Just the concept of determining the position of axis of rotation, which quantities are conserved/can be equated?

Comment: Is the force applied perpendicular or parallel to the length or at some angle w.r.t. length? Does it matter?

Comment: @DanBenson  what is the rotation axis? Through which point does it pass? The angular momentum depends on the  position of the rotation axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us denote $\ P$ the point corresponding to the end of the rod with no force applied, then we apply a force $\ \overrightarrow{F} $ on the other end of the rod, such that is parallel to the plane and perpendicular to the rod. 
Now, with respect to the center of mass, the only force whose torque is different from zero is $\ \overrightarrow{F}$:
$$\vec{M_{cm}}=\overrightarrow{R}\times\overrightarrow{F}$$
Now, projecting this equation on an axis with versor $\hat{a}$ perpendicular to the plane, we get:
$$\ M_a=RF=\frac{b}{2}F=I_a\dot{\omega}=I_a\alpha=\frac{mb^2}{12}\alpha$$
$$\ \implies \alpha=\frac{6F}{mb}$$
Where $\alpha$ is the angular acceleration around the center of mass.

So at distance $\frac{b}{2}$ from the center of mass, the acceleration is 
$$\ a=\alpha \frac{b}{2}-\frac{F}{m}=\frac{2F}{m}$$

Because for the center of mass, we have that $\sum \vec{F}=m\vec{a_{cm}}\implies a_{cm}=\frac{F}{m}$

And this is in the opposite direction.

The generic force, applied at distance $\ r$ from the center, gives a torque:

$$\ \ M=rF=\frac{mb^2}{12}\alpha\implies \alpha=\frac{12rF}{mb^2}$$

So, in order to have $\ a=0 $ for the point $\ P$, you must have:
$$\ a=\alpha \frac{b}{2}-\frac{F}{m}=\frac{6rF}{mb}-\frac{F}{m}=0$$
$$\ \implies 6\frac{r}{b}=1\implies r=\frac{1}{6}b$$

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I couldn't get my head round the fact that the center of mass must still accelerate at F/M regardless of position of force! Thanks again!